# Load SVG-Edit in browser locale

Tags: javascript, localization, internationalization, svg-edit

How do i load the svg-edit in browser locale.I want to load the tools in browser language especially chinese.
Anyone please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version is set up to already check the browser locale. You can also indicate the language within the URL, e.g., https://svg-edit.github.io/svgedit/releases/latest/editor/svg-editor.html?lang=zh-CN  . Note that the latest version (not yet released) has some additional translations for extensions in Chinese; this version can be viewed at https://raw.githack.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit/master/editor/svg-editor.html?lang=zh-CN .